# Android: handling clicks on ImageView placed inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, android-recyclerview

I just moved from `ListView` to `RecyclerView` and I'm facing an issue: I can't get the `ImageView's` onClickListener working. Basically what I want is to display the image in full screen mode inside a new activity when the user clicks it.

Something like this:

[image]

What I tried:

```
@Override
    public PaletteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

        return new PaletteViewHolder(itemView);

    }
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PaletteViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        Palette palette = palettes.get(position);
        holder.text1.setText(palette.getName());
        holder.text2.setText(palette.getHexValue());
        final Context context = holder.img.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(DaciaData.DaciaModele[position])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size)
                .centerInside()
                .tag(context)
                .into(holder.img);

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //add data to your bundle
                bundle.putInt("id", position);
                //create intent
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, Extra1.class);
                //add bundle to intent
                mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                //start activity
                context.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT**

The `RecyclerItemClickListener`:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }
}
```

`MainRecyclerView` this is where I define the `RecyclerView` along with the `onItemTouchListener`:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerModels);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLM.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLM);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(                 
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("id", position);

                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainViewPager.class);
                        i.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
        );
```

Removing `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener();` will solve the issue with the image long click, but I won't be able to start the `ViewPager`, I guess there's something wrong with the `RecyclerItemClickListener`.

Comment: What happens after you click the image?

Comment: When a row is clicked, a ViewPager is launched along with the tabs and when the image is clicked same thing happens, the ViewPager is shows up...

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: As I already said: `Basically what I want is to display the image in full screen mode inside a new activity **when the user clicks it.**` Right now when I click the Image it acts like I'm clicking on the row, it launches the wrong activity. The ImageView's onClickListener is not working.

Comment: use setTag ans get Tag

Comment: Updated my post. You actually don't need `setTag` and `getTag`. Thanks to pskink i updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my late answer, I eventually solved this problem. All I had to do was to remove the `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(...);`, then I implemented `View.OnClickListener` in my Adapter and then I set the `OnClickListener` method for the `TextView` and `ImageView`, like so:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected TextView textView;
        protected ImageView imageView;

        public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            imageview = (ImageView)  v.findViewById(R.id.img);

            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageview.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    

        if (v.getId() == textView.getId()) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "TextView Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (v.getId() == imageView.getId()) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "ImageView Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Right now when I click the Image it acts like I'm clicking on the row,
>   it launches the wrong activity. The ImageView's onClickListener is not
>   working.

Use `setTag` and `getTag`

```
 holder.img.setTag(position);
 holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Integer pos = (Integer)view.getTag(); 
            // returns an object hence the casting

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //add data to your bundle

            Log.i("Position is",""+pos.intValue);

            bundle.putInt("id", pos.intValue());
            // get int value
            //create intent
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, Extra1.class);
            //add bundle to intent
            mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            //start activity
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
```

Edit:

As pskink suggested you can eliminate the need of setTag and getTag by just having the click listener in your ViewHolder. This will make sure you click on the correct row item and move to next activity.

To get position you can use `getLayoutPosition()` in your RecyclerView view holder

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition%28%29

Edit 2:

Code:

```
  img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Element at " + getLayoutPosition () + " clicked.");

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //add data to your bundle
            bundle.putInt("id", getLayoutPosition());
            //create intent
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, Extra1.class);
            //add bundle to intent
            mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            //start activity
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
```

Edit 3:

Instead of annonymous inner class your ViewHolder class can implement interface`View.OnClickListener`

Then just override `onClick` and set `OnClickListener` to your views.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84465/discussion-on-answer-by-raghunandan-android-handling-clicks-on-imageview-placed).

Comment: for edit 2: i suggested `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to implement `View.OnClickListener` and not to create `View.OnClickListener` as an inner anonymous class (class PaletteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the EXACT same issue as you. RecyclerView that needed

- onItemClick
- onItemLongClick
- onClick on view inside the row

And if clicked on view inside the row, onClick from view was called, aswell as onItemClick on the row.

The solution is to, return false for your RecyclerView onItemClick, and instead set onClick listener to your ViewHolder main row layout (same as you set your view listener inside row, set it to row's main layout).

Return false for onItemClick for your RecyclerView

```
@Override 
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

And in `onBindViewHolder` get your main row layout, and set the onClickListener there

```
holder.mainRowLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle row item click
    }
});
```

This works, if you need any further help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this code that will help you:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("filepath", filepath.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
```

In next activity right this code ,you can get image which will display in full screen.

```
 Bundle b=new Bundle();
 if(b!=null){
     String imagepath=b.getString("filepath");
 }
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath.get(position));
 imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
holder.img.setId(position);
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //add data to your bundle
                bundle.putInt("id", view.getId());
                //create intent
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, Extra1.class);
                //add bundle to intent
                mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                //start activity
                context.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not working, actually it messes up the row: the 2 `TextView` are overlapping the `ImageView`.

Comment: Write `OnCreateViewHolder` method